# Are there the number n such that n concatenated with itself twice is a triperiod square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are the numbers n such that n concatenated with itself is a biperiod square (That is $ n = a_0 a_1 … a_0 a_1 … (10) = a 10^m + a = k^2$ where $10^{m - 1} \le a < 10^m$).

For example,

$$ 1322314049613223140496 = 36363636364^2$$.

(http://oeis.org/A102567)

Are there the number n such that n concatenated with itself twice is a triperiod square (That is $ n = a_0 a_1 … a_0 a_1 … a_0 a_1 … (10) = a 10^{2m} + a 10^m + a = k^2$ where $10^{m - 1} \le a < 10^m$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the number of digits of the period. Let $s$ be the squarefree part of $1+10^d+10^{2d}$ (observe that $3\mid s$.) Then the possible $n$'s are of the form
$$
k^2\,s\,(1+10^d+10^{2d}),\quad k\in\mathbb N,
$$
where $k^2\,s$ has $d$ digits. This implies in particular that $s$ must have at most $d$ digits. A search with Mathematica has found that there are no solutions with $d\le49$.

Answer (score 0):

In other words $a10^n + a = k^2$.

So we need to solve
 $a(10^n + 1) = k^2$ where $10^{n-1} < a < 10^n$.

My algorithm is as follows.

If $n,x,y,$ and $z$ can be found such that

$10^n + 1 = x^2y$

$z^2y$ has $n$ digits.

then $a = z^2 y$ and $k = xyz$.

Using Wolfram Alpha, I found the following

---

\begin{align}
  10^{11} + 1 = 11^2 \times 826446281 
  &\quad  (n = 11, \; x = 11, \; y = 826446281 )\\
  10^{10} < 4^2y = 13223140496 < 10^{11}
  &\quad (z = 4)\\
  a = z^2 y = 13223140496\\
  k = xyz = 36363636364\\
  1322314049613223140496 &= 36363636364^2
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
  10^{21} + 1 = 7^2 \times 20408163265306122449
  &\quad  (n = 21, \; x = 7, \; y = 20408163265306122449)\\
  10^{20} < 4^2 y = 326530612244897959184 < 10^{21}
  &\quad (z = 4)\\
  a = z^2 y = 326530612244897959184\\
  k = xyz = 571428571428571428572\\
  326530612244897959184326530612244897959184 &= 571428571428571428572^2
\end{align}

---

Which got me to thinking about special cases.

If we wanted $x = 11$, then we need $n$ such that $10^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{121}$. Since $\phi(121) = 121 - 11 = 110$, Then $n$ must be a proper divisor of $110$. Obviously $n = 11$.  Which means that $n = 11 + 22m$. So the next good value would be $n = 33$.

\begin{align}
  10^{33} + 1 = 11^2 \times 8264462809917355371900826446281 & \\
  \quad  (n = 33, \; x = 11, \; y = 8264462809917355371900826446281) & \\
  4^2 y = 132231404958677685950413223140496 \text{ has 33 digits} & \\
  (z = 4, a = 132231404958677685950413223140496 ) & \\
  k = xyz = 363636363636363636363636363636364 & \\
  132231404958677685950413223140496132231404958677685950413223140496 = 363636363636363636363636363636364 ^2 & 
\end{align}

I should mention that $z \in \{4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ also work.

Comment: You mension in the case of $ a 10^n + a$. Do you have any idea of $ a 10^{2 n} + a 10^n + a$?

Comment: @Manyama The problem with the triperiod case is that the prime divisor, $x$, of $N = 10^{2n} + 10^n + 1$ has to be large enough so that $\dfrac Nx$ is a less than n-digit number. I just don't have the resources to search for sucn a number.